# Erro. WARN: WELD-000335: Conversation context is already active

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee, jboss-weld

Estou com a apresentação do seguinte erro na saída do meu servidor Glassfish 4.1:

> WARN:   WELD-000335: Conversation context is already active, most
>   likely it was not cleaned up properly during previous request
>   processing: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@37607e3b

Estou trabalhando com jsf, cdi, primefaces, jpa. Já pesquisei por alguns dias sobre o erro mas não consegui resolver. Meu Projeto está rodando(localhost) aparentemente sem problema, mas a mensagem está sempre aparecendo.

Comment: Não precisa se preocupar, warnings não são erros, esse bug é relatado na doc do weld só que para o tomcat e por algum motivo o Grizzly se comporta semelhante, no caso do tomcat ele não permite uma integração com ThreadLocal em requisições de servlets assíncronas, então ele alerta que o conversation context já se encontra ativo, mais dúvidas veja as [docs](http://weld.cdi-spec.org/documentation/)

Comment: Obrigado Dilnei,  Estou migrando meu projeto para cdi e estou apanhando um pouco.  Estou com um problema ao fazer o deploy no servidor, achei que teria relação com o problema. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Tem algum erro? se quiser compartilhar o problema fique a vontade.

Comment: Acabei de criar um pergunta sobre o erro. Muito obrigado!

Comment: @DilneiCunha, coloca a resposta da declaração para marcar como resolvido. Apos a mudança da dependência do cdi resolveu tbm a msg que estava aparecendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warnings não são erros, esse bug é relatado na doc do weld só que para o tomcat e por algum motivo o Grizzly se comportou semelhante quando havia mais de uma lib do Weld no contexto, no caso do tomcat ele não permite uma integração com ThreadLocal em requisições de servlets assíncronas, então ele alerta que o conversation context já se encontra ativo. mas no caso do Glassfish é a lib do weld declarada no pom.xml e em conflito com a dependência CDI disponibilizada pelo container.

A solução para remoção do warning foi configurar a biblioteca correta do CDI como provided, ex:

Foi removido esta dependência:

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId> 
    <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId> 
    <version>1.1.10.Final</version> 
    <scope>compile</scope> 
</dependency>
```

e adicionado a API do CDI como provided, ex:

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId> 
    <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId> 
    <scope>provided</scope> 
</dependency>
```